# How to handle shared dependencies of an Android Libary and an App

Tags: android, android-library

I'm building an android library and I'm a little lost about how to handle dependencies of other libraries.

My main issue is that some will be shared with the app that's going to use the library initially(we plan to distribute the library, but already have an app that will use it). Specifically, we are going to use RxJava to fire events in the library and catch them on the app.

My question is where should that dependency be. If we add it to both sides we will end up with having to maintain it in both places and eventually will be a headache.

Comment: I have a similar scenario, a library that is used by my app as well as apps developed by others (the library and app are separate android projects). The library has dependencies on some open source components. When the library is built, part of the build process results in it being published to a maven repo, along with a pom that indicates the open source dependencies. When I include the library in my app, I grab it from the maven repo, but I don't have to include the dependencies of the library as gradle recognizes its dependencies and includes them automatically from maven central.

Comment: Just as an update, I ended up deciding not to have any dependency... if possible, in my library. This way we won't have issues with different dependency versions and such. And after a more arduous analysis all the dependencies the library might need won't be used in ht e app.